# How to check if string does not contain many substrings in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a string like this:

```
$string = "Test file.cs file.sql file.xml"
```

I want to check if the string contains a file with `.sql` and not contains a file with `.cs` and many other file extensions.

So far I have a very long script to check it:

```
if($string.Contains(".sql") -and (!$string.Contains(".cs") -or (!$string.Contains(".js")))) # and more....
```

Is there easy way to do it?

Something like:

```
$ext = "cs,css,js,xml"
if(!$string.Cotnains($ext))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest regex here:

```
$exts= '\.(cs|css|js|xml)'
$string = 'Test file.cs file.sql file.xml'

$string -notmatch $extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood the question wrong, but you may want to look at the `-in` operator like so:

```
$string = "Test file.cs file.sql file.xml"
$extensions = "cs", "css", "js", "xml"

if ($string -in $extensions) {
    "$string not in ext"
} else {
    "$string in ext"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the valuable [TheIncorrigible1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57291658/3439404):

```
$extsContain = '\.(sql)\b'
$extsRefused = '\.(cs|css|js|xml)\b'
$strings =  'Test1 file.cs  file.sql file.xm',
            'Test2 file.ces file.qls file.yml',
            'Test3 file.csa file.sql file.xml',
            'Test4 file.csa file.sql file.pxml',
            'Test5 file.csa file.rql file.axml'

@($strings) -match $extsContain -notmatch $extsRefused
```

**Output**:

```
D:\PShell\SO\57291315.ps1
```

> ```
> Test4 file.csa file.sql file.pxml
> ```

Comment: Note that this will only work if you're testing against an array, otherwise the second match will be testing against the string literal `True` or `False`.